# How to make the input disabled with z-index in javascript or react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i want to disable input meaning unable for user to input something in the input element.

What i am trying to do?

i have two popups (one showing info and other with input element, cancel and submit buttons). now these two are rendered from the same div whose z-index is higher than all other elements in the application. meaning when these dialogues show up the user is unable to click any other element.

Now the problem is i dont want the user to input anything into the input element which is inside the dialogue that i mentioned above.

is there a way that i can do it somehow with z-index? i dont want to add some disabled property to input since it might break the code somewhere.

Below is the html code,

```css
#root {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 25;
}

.input_dialog {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.info_dialog {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="info_dialog">some info</div>
  <div class="input_dailog">
    <form>
      <div class="input_with_actions">
        <input>
        <div class="actions">
          <button>cancel</button>
          <button>submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _I dont want to add some disabled property to input since it might break the code somewhere._  That makes this an X/Y problem

Comment: You can add display:none; to input if you don't want to user write anything to it. Or just remove it with {enableInput && <input/>}. But I don't understand why disabling input would break anything.

Comment: I think a negative z-index may work as well as setting the opacity to 0

Comment: @Michael when you add the opacity to 0 it will not be visible. I think the question is referring show the input field but using using css how to disable the field

Comment: Ok, wasn't clear on that, although very strange since disable is a native html attribute that would be the way to go.

Comment: yes using only css

Comment: disabling input would break because i am using it somewhere else too...

Comment: @someuser2491 added the answer, using pointer-events to none the field will be displayed but the user can't type on it.

Comment: @someuser2491 Can you change the html a bit ? or is it also not possible.

Answer (score -1):

using css you can use `pointer-events: none`

```css
#root {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 25;
}

.input_dialog {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.info_dialog {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="info_dialog">some info</div>
  <div class="input_dialog">
    <form>
      <div class="input_with_actions">
        <input tabindex='-1'>
        <div class="actions" >
          <button>cancel</button>
          <button>submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update** as ankit pointed out the pointer-events doesn't work for the tab navigation. So either you need to give tabindex a negative value , readonly or disabled (will have dimmed css effect)

Comment: But using, keyboard tab, you can focus the input and type.